# Использование ссылок в BundleConfig

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

У меня есть много файлов, к которым я подключаюсь вот так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://"></script>
```

Молу ли я не скачивая сами файлы, использовать ссылки на `.js` и `.css` файлы в `BundleConfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее нет, чем да.

Посмотрите код `System.Web.Optimization`. У ScriptBundle и StyleBundle есть перегрузка, которая принимает не только virtualPath, но и cdnPath (путь не на локальной файловой системе, а в интернете).

```
public StyleBundle(string virtualPath)

/// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle" /> class with virtual path and CDN path for the bundle. </summary>
/// <param name="virtualPath">A virtual path for the bundle.</param>
/// <param name="cdnPath">A CDN path for the bundle.</param>
public StyleBundle(string virtualPath, string cdnPath)
```

Это не совсем то, что вы спрашиваете, это для [работы с CDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-a-cdn). При этом в debug у вас будет использоваться локальный файл, а в release - из интернета.

Если же файлы расположены ТОЛЬКО в интернете, то вам лучше обойтись без механизма BundleConfig и располагать ссылки прямо в коде, например, как в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25131218/5752652).